# Export just the route within bbox from Overpass Turbo, not the tags / way points?

Tags: geojson, features, overpass-turbo

I'd like to

- export just the route from an Overpass Turbo query as GeoJson, and
- ideally just within a specified radius of a set of coordinates.

I have the query below, but this exports tags / waypoints along the way as shown.  I want to use the route within leaflet (for which I know I need to Export to GeoJson).

```
[out:json][timeout:25];
// gather results
(
  area[name="West Midlands"];
  way[name ~"^(Bristol Road|Binley Road)"]({{bbox}});
);
// print results
out body;
>;
out geom qt;
```

This outputs the following map, where you can see the route and also the circles (its those I want to exclude) that may well be the nodes, but I'm not sure.  They may also indicate parts of the route as I can see there are many Features defined as LineStrings.  Basically, all I want is the LineStrings.

If anyone knows how to limit to a radius of a specified point for each road, that would be great, but if needs be I can use bbox.

[image]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It seems all you have to do is to leave out recourse down `>;` part of your query (see https://wiki.openstreetmap.org/wiki/Overpass_API/Overpass_QL#Recurse_down_.28.3E.29).
Your query would then look like this:

```
[out:json][timeout:25];
// gather results
(
  area[name="West Midlands"];
  way[name ~"^(Bristol Road|Binley Road)"]({{bbox}});
);
// print results
out body;
out geom qt;
```

On the Overpass Turbo map you will still see some markers:
[image]

But if you drill down (zoom in) enough, they'll disappear:

[image]

And if you export result into GeoJSON and then drop it down into https://geojson.io/, you'll see only ways, no points/markers/nodes:

[image]

Comment: Perfect, thank you @TomazicM